# Android: how to send notifications to many activities

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, message, observer-pattern

Inside my Application class, I have a long-running function (e.g. downloading new data). Once the operation finishes, I want to inform several related activities to refresh their UI. What is the best way to achieve this in Android (the equivalent of postNotification in iOS)?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    public void onCreate() {
        downloadDataInBackground(); // call operationDone when finished
    }

    private void operationDone(){
        sendMessageToAllRelatedActivities();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: Broadcast Receivers for this. Please see following link:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the Observer design pattern in order to notify that a certain status is changed

[Observer](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html)